# WordPress Cleartext Password Stored In Browser Memory

Tags: wordpress, security, browser, passwords, penetration-testing

I have been performing penetration testing on a stock WordPress install. A persistence concern I see is that WP stores cleartext passwords within the browser memory.

**To reproduce:**

1. Login to WordPress and then log back out. Close that particular tab,
   but keep Chrome open.
2. Create a dump file of the browser memory.
3. Open the dump file and search for the password, you will then see it present in clear text.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Regardless of the context of someone actually viewing the password this way, the use of a cleartext password cannot be good practice?

Ref: https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/316.html

Comment: What tool did u use for the export?  Official browser plugin, nirsoft, etc.?

Comment: Hi @f.overflow, actually this can be done without any tool. In Task Manager => Applications, right click Chrome and click "Create Dump File". Open that file, and search for your WP password and it can be seen as text.

Answer (score 1):

**"How can I prevent this from happening?"**

This is not a WordPress issue, as WordPress doesn't control the client's garbage collection. The password would disappear in short time, when the JavaScript engine would be available for this task.

**"the use of a cleartext password cannot be good practice?"**

The browser is passing clear text password to WordPress, this is how username-password authentication (also called basic authentication) works.

Comment: Thanks, surely WP is at fault? Should WP not store user credentials in the browser memory. Passwords should be encrypted or stored in salted hash format. Ref: https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/316.html

Comment: The password is stored in the browser memory, hence the relevant application is the browser's JVM.

WP is considered as an application only on the WP server. Interesting enough, PHP have exactly the same issue.

The reason it is not mitigated on script language (JS, PHP) is the short life-time of a script. Java and C# have objects that holds string encrypted in their heap.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your comments. JVM, you mean the browser memory right?

Comment: I wrote JVM but meant the rendering engine, as this is an html input and not a JS variable. 
The answer is still the same, it's up to the client garbage collection algorithm to clean up the memory.
Btw: If you would use a multi-process browser, such as Google Chrome, you won't experience this issue when closing tab, because the relevant processes would be terminated immediately. However, this does not mean that Chrome is safer, because the same issue would happen when you'd reuse the same tab.

Comment: N.b. that WordPress does not use HTTP's [Basic Authentification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme) (`AuthType Basic`, `http://user:pass@example.com/` etc.)

Comment: @kubi can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @David.J i was referring to the answer: "…this is how username-password authentication (also called basic authentication) works.". While you _could_ call this 'a basic _form of_ authentification', I know 'basic authentification' only in context of HTTP, and the first couple of search result pages seem to agree. WP does send credentials over HTTP, but it is not Basic Authentification.